# Dynamically resizing font and text size when changing the window size in Kivy app

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create some base classes that I can use on all of my screens throughout my kivy app. These 2 classes are meant to dynamically adjust the font size, text size, and wrap text of widgets on every screen (mainly labels and buttons) to fit the screen size if I make the kivy window smaller or bigger. Currently, it *does* work for the most part but I'm running into this problem that when I resize the screen all of the fonts immediately change to be the same exact size so while the fonts do get smaller as the screen does, they are not getting smaller relative to their original sizes, all the labels and buttons will just have the same font size going forward and it affects all of the screens.

I tried changing the logic and moving things around. I also put it into chat gpt and it gave some suggestions that I incorporated but I still can't figure it out. I am new to python and OOP so any help would be appreciated!

```
class InitialResize(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_resize=self.on_window_resize)

    def on_window_resize(self, instance, width, height):
        font_size_height = int(height / 30)
        font_size_width = int(width / 80)

        font_size = min(font_size_height, font_size_width)

        for widget in self.walk():
            if hasattr(widget, 'font_size'):
                widget.font_size = sp(font_size)


class Font_Wrap_Resize(InitialResize):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def update_text_size(self, *args):
        font_size = int(self.height / 30)
        
        for widget in self.walk():
            if isinstance(widget, (Label, Button)):
                widget.font_size = sp(font_size)
                widget.text_size = (widget.width, None)

    def on_window_resize(self, instance, width, height):
        super().on_window_resize(instance, width, height)
```

Comment: this is only part of the code, so identifying the problem (from the code) is difficult.  But the procedure will be that you would need to run the function on each font sequentially (independently), which presumably the code is not currently doing...